# spring-security not invalidating http sessions

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have a soap web service and i implemented a spring security authentication.

I generated a client which is used in the front end.

My problem is that each time the client makes a request the web-service generates a session and than the session just stays there, session never gets invalidated.

Here is my part of web.xml file:

`<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>`

What I need is that the session should get invalidated after each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security http element has a attribute 'create-session' which can be set to 'stateless' after which a session will never be created.

E.g.

```
<http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="stateless">
  <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_REMOTE' />
  <http-basic />
</http>
```

Documentation here:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Comment: Great exactly what i what looking for, i even think ive read that link but just the upper part!!!